# Odd issue with loading cloud folders in File Explorer (Windows 11)

Tags: windows

This doesn't happen with local files, but it *always* happens with Dropbox, OneDrive and Box:

1. Open folder, contents show up immediately, I can open files or subfolders with no lag
2. But the blue circle next to the pointer *never* goes away —- and the main practical issue I've noticed is that it won't let me sort the folder contents

[image]

So this started a few months ago, and most of the advice I can find online seems to be about slow loading or indexing. I can't find anyone describing my exact issue of loading immediately but never finishing. It seems more like a bug than a capacity issue...?

Comment: What icon exactly are you referring to?

Comment: added image above

Comment: It could be the Search indexer is running, a Defender or other malware scan is in process, etc.  Open Task Manager, details, and see what processes are using drive I/O (and CPU) that might keep that sync connection open.

Answer (score 0):

The blue circle indicates that some process is working in the background.
I can't say which program is that and why it's activated when you're
on a cloud folder, but the following method might at least get rid
of the blue circle:

- Run *Control Panel > Mouse* to open the Mouse Properties window
  (or press Win+R and run `main.cpl`)
- Position to the Pointers tab
- Under "Customize" select "Working in background"
- Click on Browse
- Select `aero_arrow.cur` (the first when the list is sorted by name)
- Click on Open.

For more information see the article
[How to Fix Spinning Blue Circle Windows 10](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/spinning-blue-circle-windows-10.html).

Comment: That hides the indication of the issue, but not the issue itself. It would also prevent showing the "working" arrow in other instance3s, e.g., writing to disk, where it might be useful to know an operation has not completed.